# How do i use .html in to display multiple records

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the following code to get a list of members and their information using ajax, jquery, php, json.
The only problem is when i use .html   , it only displays the first record, it doesn't display all of the records. Totally confused.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).delegate("#member_home", "pagecreate", function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        var friends= new Array();
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://www.l.example.com/app/scrip/friends_lookup.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    var friend = val['friend'];
                    var phone = val['phone'];
                    var status = val['status'];
                    var email = val['email'];
                    var updated = val['updated'];  
                    $('#member_friends').append("<div class='member-box'>"+friend+"<span class='status-pic1'><img src='images/"+status+".png' width='40' height='40'/></span><span class='phone_box'><a href='tel:"+phone+"'><img src='images/icons/phone.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><span class='email-box'><a href='mailto:"+email+"'><img src='images/mail.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><div class='clear'></div><span class='update-status'><i>last update:&nbsp;"+updated+"</i></span>");

                });                                             
            }                                                 
        });
    }, 1500);
});

</script>
```

I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).delegate("#member_home", "pagecreate", function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {                                            
        var friends= new Array();
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.l.example.com/pp/scripts/friends_lookup.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var output = [];
                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                    output[output.length] = {
                        friend  : data[i].friend,
                        phone   : data[i].phone,
                        status  : data[i].status,
                        email   : data[i].email,
                        updated : data[i].updated
                    };                                                  

                    $('#member_friends').html("<div class='member-box'>"+friend+"<span class='status-pic1'><img src='images/"+status+".png' width='40' height='40'/></span><span class='phone_box'><a href='tel:"+phone+"'><img src='images/icons/phone.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><span class='email-box'><a href='mailto:"+email+"'><img src='images/mail.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><div class='clear'></div><span class='update-status'><i>last update:&nbsp;"+updated+"</i></span>");
                }
            }
        });                                        
    }, 1500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whats with the indenting on your code? Hard to read...

Comment: I apologize i copied it from my editor and for some reason it got screwed up

Comment: possible duplicate of [For some reason I can't get my jquery code to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204052/for-some-reason-i-cant-get-my-jquery-code-to-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-writing the values each iteration of your `$.each` loop. Before the loop, create an array to store the data, then add to the array each iteration:

```
$.ajax({
    success : function (data) {
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            output[output.length] = {
                friend  : data[i].friend,
                phone   : data[i].phone,
                status  : data[i].status,
                email   : data[i].email,
                updated : data[i].updated
            };
        }
        //you now have an array of objects that each contain a set of information
    }
});
```

The `for` loop I used is quite fast, here's a JSPerf to show the performance increase over using `$.each()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Also you may have noticed that I used `output[output.length] = ...` instead of `output.push(...)`. The former performs faster in old browsers (the latter performs faster in modern browsers), I tend to try to help the old browsers out since they really need the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that when you use .html() within a loop, for every iteration, it will replace all content added with the .html() during the previous iteration. Logically that would however leave you with only the last record, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call .html() after the loop, currently it will replace the contents of #member_friends
in every loop iteration, so you will always see the last item.

This should be the workaround:

```
var output = [];
var html = []
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    output[output.length] = {
        friend  : data[i].friend,
        phone   : data[i].phone,
        status  : data[i].status,
        email   : data[i].email,
        updated : data[i].updated
    };                                                  

    html.push("<div class='member-box'>"+friend+"<span class='status-pic1'><img src='images/"+status+".png' width='40' height='40'/></span><span class='phone_box'><a href='tel:"+phone+"'><img src='images/icons/phone.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><span class='email-box'><a href='mailto:"+email+"'><img src='images/mail.png' width='40' height='40' /></a></span><div class='clear'></div><span class='update-status'><i>last update:&nbsp;"+updated+"</i></span>");
}//end of for
$('#member_friends').html(html.join(''));
```